# Can Hacker Get My Code through Ad-Hoc Files?

Tags: iphone, security, adhoc

If I send out Ad Hoc distributions of my App, is it possible for someone to hack the included files and get my code? I know it is compiled, but that Ad Hoc folder has a lot of stuff in it.

Comment: I don't believe there's anything in the ad-hoc version that isn't also in the App Store version (other than provisioning). You can get to all the resources and binaries in them too.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, they could de-compile your code.

But the reality is that de-compiled code is not very useful, and I'm not even sure there are any decompilers at the moment.

To help, you can make sure that ad-hoc builds do not ship with symbols included (by default I don't think Release distributions do).  That would make it pretty hard to follow code even if decompiled...

Basically, I would not worry about that at all.

Comment: I disagree. Disassembly can reconstruct the code logic and is enough to break any secrets built inside the binary e.g. DRM. And even if you strip the binary, the ObjC symbols and strings cannot be removed which is often enough to tell what is going on.

Comment: I'm reading some things that say "Obviously - how do you think people are modifying the iPhone System Code, they can obviously get into an app."